# Load a big file at pandas and filter columns before loadings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I´m trying to load a csv at pandas, but my computer keeps freezing. The csv has more than 20k columns and 500k rows, but I only need a few to them

```
df = pd.read_csv('e:/teste/teste/file.txt', sep="|", header=None, encoding="latin1", error_bad_lines=False, engine= 'python', dtype='unicode', usecols = [4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25,26,56,93])
```

The computer hangs if I load just a few of the columns.
Anyone knows how can I fix it?

Comment: you probably need to specify your dtypes but it shouldn't hang for 20 or so columns. maybe preprocess with Python in chunks and then read into pandas.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to read a big file the best way to do it is with chunks

```
mylist = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=Number):
    mylist.append(chunk)
df = pd.concat(mylist, axis= 0)
```

Put the chunk in an array and later concatenate all chunks. Is more memory efficent than concatenate in every iteration.

And for the columns in the [docs of pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) there's a *usecols* parameter, I hope it helps

Comment: Hello. I ´m using usecols as I posted, but the file keeps hanging. I´ve tried chuck,but doesn´t seemns to solve my problem. Thanks anyone

Comment: are you already using the low_memory? if the column types are not specified pandas  tries to guess and also consumes a lot of memory.